# Is there a way to print the date that an application was last published?

Tags: c#

By using `System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment.CurrentVersion` one can identify the publish version of an application in C#.

Is there a way to identify the date when the application was last published?  I'd like to add a "Last Updated:" line to my About... dialog.

Comment: As far as I know, you'd have to put an entry inside a file somewhere (which means a post-build event), and then read up that file somehow from your application. It's not exactly an easy thing to do.

Comment: `DateTime lastModified = File.GetLastWriteTime(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase.Substring(8));` How about this? The Substring(8) is to get rid of the file:/// prefix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about when the app was built?

`System.IO.File.GetLastWriteTime(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location)`

Answer (score 1):

See Jeff Atwood's [blog](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/04/determining-build-date-the-hard-way.html). A nice & tricky way